# Go migrate will not install on MacOS

Tags: bash, macos, go, command-line

Mac OS here. I have Go version go1.14.2 darwin/amd64 installed locally under `~/go` and in my `~/.bash_profile` I have:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/repos
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"

export GOPATH=/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/repos

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/repos/bin
```

I am trying to get [go migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) working. When I run:

```
go get -tags 'postgres' -u github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate
```

I get:

```
$ go migrate
go migrate: unknown command
```

So then I tried downloading the [binary directly off of GitHub](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/releases) and have copied it to `/Users/myuser/workspace/myproject/repos/bin/`:

```
$ ls -al ~/myuser/myproject/repos/bin/
total 391744
drwxr-xr-x  22 myuser  staff       704 Sep 22 12:41 .
drwxr-xr-x  18 myuser  staff       576 Aug 20 05:41 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff  18485484 Jun 15 12:38 dlv
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   6790688 Jun 15 12:38 fillstruct
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   4588168 Jun 15 12:37 go-outline
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   4385080 Jun 15 12:37 go-symbols
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff  13219700 Jun 15 12:37 gocode
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff  12768972 Jun 15 12:38 gocode-gomod
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   9168808 Jun 15 12:38 godef
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   8031416 Jun 15 12:38 godoctor
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   5851000 Jun 15 12:38 goimports
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   6301816 Jun 15 12:38 golint
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   4678536 Jun 15 12:37 gomodifytags
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   5448568 Jun 15 12:37 gopkgs
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   7438724 Jun 15 12:38 goplay
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   6291392 Jun 15 12:37 gorename
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   7990696 Jun 15 12:38 goreturns
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff  13191844 Jun 15 12:37 gotests
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   9443888 Jun 15 12:37 guru
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   6060712 Jun 15 12:37 impl
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 myuser  staff  41461192 Aug  3 21:34 migrate.darwin-amd64
-rwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff   7896368 Jun 25 05:27 mockgen
```

But still, when I run `go migrate` I get errors:

```
$ go migrate
go migrate: unknown command
```

Given where I have Go downloaded and all my path settings, which I **really** don't want to change, how can I install `go migrate` successfully and make it work from the command line?

---

When I run:

```
$ which migrate
$
```

So it is not installed.

Comment: `go` is the Go toolchain; Go migrate is its own program, not a part of the Go toolchain. Based on what you've shown, the command should just be `migrate`.

Comment: This is even covered in the project documentation right on the front page of the repo: https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate#basic-usage

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, please see my updates. Either way, I need the tool installed -- any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually called `migrate`, you can check its location by running  `which migrate` or `command -v migrate`, or call binary  from your bin folder `migrate.darwin-amd64`